# Storing and evaluating nested string elements

Tags: python, parsing

Given the `exampleString = "[9+[7*3+[1+2]]-5]"`
How does one extract and store elements enclosed by [] brackets, and then evaluate them in order?

```
1+2 --+
      |
  7*3+3 --+
          |
        9+24-5
```

Does one have to create somekind of nested list? Sorry for this somewhat *broad* question and bad English.

I see, this question is really too broad... Is there a way to create a nested list from that string? Or maybe i should simply do regex search for every element and evaluate each? The nested list option (if it exists) would be a IMO "cleaner" approach than looping over same string and evaluating until theres no [] brackets.

Comment: If you don't need the intermediate values, a simple search/replace that turns brackets into parentheses, followed by an eval, would work fine.

Comment: I see no significant problems with the English. (Insignificant problems include the lower-case proper noun and the question that doesn't end with a question mark.) I can't answer your question directly, but I suggest you search for *parsing tools*. (Python parsing tools, if you like, but your example isn't specific to Python.)

Comment: to do a quick evaluation you could simply do: `eval(exampleString.replace('[', '(').replace(']', ')'))`

Comment: It seems related to [Evaluating a mathematical expression in a string](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2371436/1132524). Take a look at [unutbu's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2371789/1132524).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a regex solution:

```
import re

def evaluatesimple(s):
  return eval(s)

def evaluate(s):
  while 1:
    simplesums=re.findall("\[([^\]\[]*)\]",s)
    if (len(simplesums) == 0):
      break
    replacements=[('[%s]' % item,str(evaluatesimple(item))) for item in simplesums]
    for r in replacements:
      s = s.replace(*r)
  return s

print evaluate("[9+[7*3+[1+2]]-5]")
```

But if you want to go the whole hog and build a tree to evaluate later, you can use the same technique but store the expressions and sub expressions in a dict:

```
def tokengen():
  for c in 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwyxz':
    yield c

def makeexpressiontree(s):
  d=dict()
  tokens = tokengen()
  while 1:
    simplesums=re.findall("\[([^\]\[]*)\]",s)
    if (len(simplesums) == 0):
      break
    for item in simplesums:
      t = tokens.next()
      d[t] = item
      s = s.replace("[%s]"% item,t)
  return d

def evaltree(d):
  """A simple dumb way to show in principle how to evaluate the tree"""
  result=0
  ev={}
  for i,t in zip(range(len(d)),tokengen()):
    ev[t] = eval(d[t],ev)
    result = ev[t]
  return result

s="[9+[7*3+[1+2]]-5]"
print evaluate(s)
tree=makeexpressiontree(s)
print tree
print evaltree(tree)
```

(Edited to extend my answer)

Comment: Thanks, that'd be a useful straightforward code. I think this could be also the easiest way to approach in contrast to nested lists.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [pyparsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/) module and some examples they have ([four function calculator](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/file/view/fourFn.py) is something you want and more).

PS. In case the size of that code worries you, look again: most of this can be stripped. The lower half are just tests. The upper part can be stripped from things like supporting e/pi/... constants, trigonometric funcitons, etc. I'm sure you can cut it down to 10 lines for what you need.

Comment: I'm going to second pyparsing, it's _exactly_ what you need to get started on this. What you want to write is not the parser, but the grammar for the (context-free) language. For me, and well worth the money, the getting started guide http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596514235.do was instrumental in getting started quickly.

Comment: Looks like a lot of useful things can be found in [pyparsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/) module. That specific [four function calculator](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/file/view/fourFn.py) is quite useful for basic math expressions and a somewhat safer alternative to eval(). Also, the example displayed in [nested.py](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/file/view/nested.py) appears to convert nested tags to **nested list**. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

A good starting point is the the [shunting-yard algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting_yard_algorithm).

There are multiple Python implementations available online; here is [one](http://andreinc.net/2010/10/05/converting-infix-to-rpn-shunting-yard-algorithm/).

The algorithm can be used to translate infix notation into a variety of representations. If you are not constrained with regards to which representation you can use, I'd recommend considering [Reverse Polish notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation) as it's easy to work with.